# Spark/Scala: Store temptable data into csv file

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

I have one program which is expecting a csv file and written in python .

The csv data is suppose to come from scala which is using spark functionality to store the data from source and store into temp table like below.

```
abb.createOrReplaceTempView("tempt")
```

`temp` is outcome of above spark command [Described](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/R/createOrReplaceTempView.html) .

I want to store the temp  data into csvfile `/tmp/something.csv`
But I did not find anything as such in scala with spark  which will serve my purpose .

Please suggest me what whould be the the best way to store `tempt`into csv file/

Comment: I'm assuming **abb** is a `DataFrame` and that you are using **Spark 2.2.0** _(since that is the version of the link - however that link is for the R documentation not for the Scaladoc). If so, you can just use the [`write` **method**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@write:org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter[T]) to get a [`DataFrameWriter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter) which as you can see from the docs and from Arnon's answer has an option to save a **csv** file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declaring "temp" as tempTable allows you to reference it when you write SQL commands in spark 
if you want to save the dataframe use `abb.write.csv("file_name")`